# how to add a uibuttonitem by calling a method from another class

Tags: xcode, uicollectionviewcell, uibuttonbaritem

Due to the neeeds of the aplication I need to call a method from a cell class of a collection view. The method is in a detail view controller which implementes the collection view .

If I call the method completely from viewDidLoad of the detail view controller at aplication start everything goes well and the button is added in the navigation bar as intended, but when I call the same method from  the cell class nothing happens. Do I forget something?

Here is the code

collectionViewCell.m

```
- (void) addButtonToNavigationBar {

DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init]
[dvc implementButton];

}
```

DetailViewController.h

```
- (void) implementButton;
```

DetailViewController.m

```
- (void) implementButton {
addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                            target:self
                                            action:@selector(editTable)];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton animated:YES];
```

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];` you are creating a new controller.  It's not the one that already exists.

For your situation, you might consider having the controller listen for a `NSNotification` from the cell and call `implementButton` when it receives it.

Comment: thanks for your indications. How would you call the existing controller and subsequently the method?

Comment: Aside of being interested on how you would call the existing controller, the use of nsnotification works well. Thank you

Comment: To use the existing controller, a reference to it would have to be passed into the cell as it was created, which seems a bit cluttered compared to notifications.